# Importing Excel file to SQLite (using SQLite Admin Tool)

Tags: sqlite, import

Excel file is not able to import to SQLite. How to import Excel file to SQLite (using SQLite Admin Tool) without any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to import CSV files, so export it as .csv in Excel first.